# Saving a two way non nullable constraint

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel project with a mysql database some constraints like this.

We have people and projects.

Every person is only assigned to exactly one project.

Every project has a manager who is a person.

So we have some foriegn keys `project_id` in person table and `manager_id` in project table and these cannot be null.

But now I have a chicken and egg project when saving because I cannot save a project without a manager and I cannot save a manager without a project.

Is there some way to do a single save operation for all of this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two way binding. Only 'project_id in person table' is enough.

Then you can define the relationship in your models. In this case, project model should have a 'hasOne' method and the person model should have a 'belongsTo' method. [Read](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) this and try to implement.

Comment: But each project must have one person who is on the project but is also a manager

Comment: No problem. You need to save a project and a person in your database at the same time. Save the project first. If you want to make sure that same project id is not used for more than one person then run a query before saving.